# two side slide menu in onsen-ui skips main page, while swiping from right menu

Tags: onsen-ui

Im implementing facebook like two side swipe menus for phone app, Im using the following code in

`code here`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGWPVj

slide right and left work fine when i use top extreme buttons, but when try swiping on phone (click drag pages on PC) there are anomalies. 
when i swipe this way

```
1) main page to left menu - works fine
2) left menu to main page - works fine
3) main page to right menu - works fine
4) right menu to main page - fails, instead of main page it goes to left menu
after 4. main page never accessible
```

i tried to nest the sliding menu in other way around then right menu gives same symptoms and left works fine.

should i stop propagating touchmove/drag event in any pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about where is the problem yet, it looks like something is buggy. I made a provisional workaround that may help you. Simply use `postopen` and `postclose` events to lock the menu you don't need:

```
<ons-sliding-menu var="rightMenu" ...
                  ons-postopen="leftMenu.setSwipeable(false);"
                  ons-postclose="leftMenu.setSwipeable(true);">
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/XbEzqq

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem, but some time i noticed its not responsive as it used to be without ons-postopen and ons-postclose, im not sure its because new hook functions. but still acceptable, as its rare to see swipe right misses

Comment: Maybe you can try with `preopen` instead of `postopen` and see if that works better for you :)